# Insert integer to an array java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to insert an integer into an array in the correct position.

For example my array is `(1,2,3,4,6)` and my integer is `5`.
The new array should be `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 5;
    int [] aray =  { 1,2,3,4,6};
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length -1 ; i++) {

       if(array[i] < a && array[i+1] > a) { 
            newArray[i]  = a; 
       }               
       newArray[i] = array[i];                                  
    }                    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works as expected.

```
int a = 4;
int[] array = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++, j++) {
    if (i == 0 && array[0] > a){
        j++;
        newArray[j] = a;
    }
    newArray[j] = array[i];
    if((i == array.length - 1 && array[i]<a)
            || (array[i] < a && array[i + 1] > a)) {
        j++;
        newArray[j] = a;
    }

}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with two loops. One to iterate copying from the original to the new until you add `a` to the `newArray`, then a second loop to copy everything left from the original array (into the `newArray`). Finally, you need a last `if` to make sure your element shouldn't be added to the end. Something like,

```
int i = 0, p = 0;
while (p < newArray.length && i < array.length) {
    if (array[i] < a) {
        newArray[p++] = array[i++];
    } else {
        newArray[p++] = a;
        break; // <-- added a, break and add the rest of the original array
    }
}
while (p < newArray.length && i < array.length) {
    newArray[p++] = array[i++];
}
if (p < newArray.length) {
    newArray[p] = a;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: You can use `System.arraycopy()` instead of `for` loop.

```
int a = 5;
int [] array =  { 1,2,3,4,6};
int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];
// 1. copy the array
System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
// 2. insert the value to the last position.
newArray[newArray.length-1] = a;
// 3. then sort the array
Arrays.sort(newArray);

// or you can swap the position for this
/*int temp = newArray[4];
newArray[4] = a;
newArray[5] = temp;*/

// 4. and it is what you want
System.out.println("newArray = " + Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

And it is the result:

```
newArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] < a && array[i + 1] > a) {
        int t = array[i + 1];
        newArray[i + 1] = a;
        newArray[i + 2] = t;
        newArray[i] = array[i];
        break;//use break
    }
    newArray[i] = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
int a = 5;
int [] aray =  { 1,2,3,4,6};
int[] newArray = new int[aray.length + 1];
for(int i=0, j=0;  i<aray.length;   i++, j++) {
      if((aray[i] > a) && (j == i)) {
            newArray[j] = a;
            j++;
       }
       newArray[j] = aray[i];
}
if(j == i) {
    newArray[j] = a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class test{
public static void main(String args[]){
        int arr[] ={1,2,3,4,5};
        int new_array[] =new int[arr.length+1];
        int e = 9;
        int p = 3;
        for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
                if(i==p){
                        new_array[i] = e;
                        continue;
                    }
                new_array[i]=arr[i];
            }
    }
```

}